# CSS Active Property not working fine

Tags: css

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/mrto2/nD2eB/.
I've given the

```
  #filters li a:active {
  border-top: 2px solid #EB2F26;
  color: #EB2F26;
  }
```

for Active font and border color but when we click on some menu, its color and border changes but it turns back while mouse release. So how can we fix this?.

Comment: What behavior do you expect from the links?

Comment: I want the top border and font color to be changed for Active menu item. But it changes only when we click on it. And when we release mouse then it's colors goes back.........any simple solution rather than js? or am i using wrong markup???

Comment: `a:active` selects `<a>`s _being clicked_, **not** _clicked_. That means there's no way to do this only with css. However I'd recommend to use a css/js framework like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), since they already bring functionalities like those in a very easy way to use.

Answer (score 0):

There's no plain CSS way to deal with this, since `link:active` selector applies to `<a>`s being clicked. You can approach this by defining a `li.active` css class and adding it to links dynamically via js.

```
li a.active {
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a>Link 4</a></li>
<ul>
```

```
// Using Jquery
$('ul.nav li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```